# Submit List of Items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using MVC, I have a textbox and unordered list:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Assets:", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.Editor("Assets", new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "Asset-Tags", @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul name="AssetsList" id="asset-list" class="list-group"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This textbox using Twitter Typeahead to aide the user in just selecting the option that they're typing, from one of my database tables.. then once the user selects the option then that option is populated into a `ul` element to allow the user to see what they've chosen before they submit.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var assets = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('assetTag'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            remote: {
                url: '/api/ItemsApi?query=%QUERY',
                wildcard: '%QUERY'
            }
        });

        $('#Asset-Tags').typeahead({
                minLength: 3,
                highlight: true,
            },
            {
                name: 'assets',
                display: 'assetTag',
                source: assets,
                limit: 20
            }).on("typeahead:select", function (e, asset) {
                $("#asset-list").append("<li class='list-group-item' value='" + asset.id + "'>" + asset.assetTag + "</li>");

            $("#Asset-Tags").typeahead("val", "");
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my controller, I have this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Phone,DateIssued,Comment,Deleted,StatusId")] BorrowedProperty borrowedProperty, List<string> AssetsList)
```

When I submit, `AssetsList` is null which I expected when trying to submit an unordered list.. so my question is.. how do I get the list of items that the user has chosen to submit to the `HttpPost` method along with the rest of the form?

**Update**

I have tried adding a name attribute to the list items like so:

```
$("#asset-list").append("<li name='AssetsList[0]' class='list-group-item'>" + asset.assetTag + "</li>");
```

Still not being submitted to server.

Answer (score 0):

While adding the items to the AssetsList you will have to index each item.

So, this line

$("#asset-list").append("" + asset.assetTag + "");

should have a name attribute with the index on it.

So item[0] should have an attribute as name=AssetsList[0] 
   item[1] should have an attribute as name=AssetsList[1]

This should bind the values as a list on the server.

Answer (score 0):

use fiddler witch help you to watch the request and the response doing by the submit

http://www.telerik.com/blogs/capturing-traffic-from-.net-services-with-fiddler